# Adding C-Wire for Nest to Triple Aquastat Relay L8148J

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

Need some extra eyes and advice on how to add a common wire to our current boiler setup. We have a Triple Aquastat L8148E that has 2 wire that connect to our thermostat. Like many before me, I'm trying to figure out how to connect a Nest to our boiler; I've already attempted with the 2 wires and the Nest is not holding a charge.

From what I've read, it sounds like I might need to add a 24v transformer and then a separate relay between the Aquastat and Nest. If I do this, do I just splice in the transformer on the power coming to the boiler (pictured).[image]

Before I do all this, I'm wondering if I can add a c-wire on the Aquastat to the "TP" terminal since currently there is nothing connected to it? Does this terminal need to have 24v for a C-wire? [image]

The "W" and "T" are the wires that run to our thermostat currently. The previous owner or HVAC person used 18/5, but cut the extra wires.

Here is the schematic that is under the lid for the Aquastat...not much of this makes sense to me so not sure if it's helpful for this question or not. Would appreciate any insight or explanations on what to do, thank you!
[image]

Comment: "The previous owner or HVAC person used 18/5, but cut the extra wires." In the one photo, it appears that there is *plenty* of extra 18/5 if you just cut back the cable jacket. I can't tell if that's a splice at the bottom or not; does the 18/5 exit the box?

Comment: @MikeWaters so the 18/5 is spliced into old two-wire between thermostat and aquastat

Comment: @toekneeoeeo -- was the thermostat *always* wired to T and W, or was that wiring changed recently?  Can you get us an exact model number for your aquastat for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel so I double checked model number and I actually have the L8148J 1009...one brief google search seems like a C-Wire connection is possible. does the theermostat need to calling for heat for me to chefk voltage? what terminals do i need the probes to touch to find 24v?

Comment: Is the existing thermostat a mechanical (analog) thermostat, or an electronic (digital) one?

Comment: Existing thermostat was analog, new one is a nest. 

couple of pieces of information...so on the aquastat there is B1, B2, B3. When I connect B3 and Z with a multmeter, I get 24v, which sends 24v to "W" with the jumper.

"T" is double wired; one wire goes to the thermostat and the other goes into the boiler. "TV" red wire goes into boiler. "W" has a red wire that goes up to the thermostat.

Soooo...can I jump Z to TP to get 24v, add a common wire to TP and then connect that to C on Nest to get voltage up there? Everything I've read about the c-wire

Comment: @toekneeoeeo -- what happens if you jumper the terminals at the existing thermostat? Does the heat kick on normally as if the thermostat was calling for heat, or does the system behave...differently? Because the way you have described the wiring leads to some quite strange system operation if the thermostat's a conventional mechanical heating-only 'stat...

Comment: What does the cable that runs off into the boiler connect to?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZJ2tch3_oc.  The B2 connector is the common connection for the 24V circuit of this relay.  It's based on the diagram for L8148J, so it may be not apply to the L8148E.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] your post to include some detail from the video since it could disappear at any moment. As it is, that could be a link to some ad for something totally unrelated, too, so some might consider it potential spam, and it effectively meets the "link only" criteria for deleting answers.